# Almacenar información del usuario temporal

Tags: javascript, array, nodejs

Para ser más claro la intención es guardar variables, dinámicamente, de los usuarios IRC que no están asociados por id sino por nombre. La intención es, dinámicamente, guardar las variables asociadas a los usuarios, ejemplo: `Usuario[Nombre][Valor]` y se cargaría la información de forma dinámica según lo ejecute el usuario, el código `Usuario[$nombre][$Estado]` y su resultado sería el número de estado por ejemplo.

Comment: No es muy claro lo que necesitas hacer. Por un lado el título sugiere que quieres almacenar valores en un array. Que valores? Tu función usuario tiene aspecto de una función constructor, pero le están faltando cosas.

Comment: Tienes una mezcla de conceptos muy grande. Si tu función recibe un parámetro llamado `nombre` y pretendes luego devolver el valor de `nombre[variable][valor]`, significa que dicho parámetro es un tipo `Array` o es un Objeto. Pero luego llamas a la función y le pasas como argumento un `String`. ¿Exactamente qué deseas lograr?

Comment: @JuanMarco He intentado por array y por funcion lo que quiero es almacenar en una variable que sea especifica del usuario ejemplo Usuario[Juan][variable][valor] que sea dinámico con todos los nombre de usuarios. Y no sé si es más correcto por constructor ó por modo array pero de ninguna de las dos formas lo logro, simplemente es para guardar unos datos temporales ligados a su nombre para poder extraerlos.

Comment: @MauricioContreras ahí se lo he especificado a Juan es que he intentado de varias formas de ahí el lio la cuestión es crear un guardado del usuario y sus variables que poder recuperar de forma temporal. Por ejemplo Usuario[Miguel][variable] ó una forma que sea más correcta.

Answer (score 2):

En `Javascript` los objetos se pueden usar como *"arreglos asociativos"*, esto te permite guardar datos utilizando indices no numéricos.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
let Usuarios = {};

// Agregamos un "usuario"
Usuarios['Marcos'] = {};
// Agregamos al usuario un "atributo"
Usuarios['Marcos']['id'] = 1;

// Existen 3 formas de acceder a la información del Usuario
// Opción 1: usando sintaxis para propiedades manuales
console.log('Marcos.id', Usuarios.Marcos.id);

// Opción 2: usando la sintaxis para propiedades dinámicas
let username = 'Marcos';
let prop = 'id';
console.log('Marcos.id', Usuarios[username][prop]);

// Opción 3: combinando ambas
console.log('Marcos.id', Usuarios.Marcos[prop]);
console.log('Marcos.id', Usuarios[username].id);

// Para saber cuantos usuarios se guardaron
console.log('Total usuarios: ', Object.keys(Usuarios).length);
```

Answer (score 0):

lo que yo haria es crear un modelo de objeto para poder reusarlo cuantas veces queramos y ademas es mucho mas facil de entender y no tendriamos que estar creando arrays con multiples variables que a la larga se hace confuso.

```
function Usuario(nombre, ID, tiempo) //aca estoy declarando las propiedades del objeto{
this.nombre = nombre 
this.ID = ID
this.tiempo = tiempo  // asigno cada propiedad dentro del objeto 
};
var listaDeObjetos = [
new Usuario("pepito", "pepito ID", "pepito tiempo"), // creo el objeto dentro de una lista
new Usuario("pedro", "pedro ID", "pedro tiempo") ];
```

Bueno y ahora si quiero acceder por ejemplo a pedro ID digo:

```
listaDeObjetos[1].ID
```

o al tiempo de pepito:

```
listaDeObjetos[0].tiempo
```

Espero haberte hecho de ayuda!

Comment: Algo así encontré antes buscando el problema es que se usará de forma dinámica no tengo forma de asociarles por id  si no por nombre de ahí la intención de crear una variable con su nombre para que sea única ó que uno de los valores sea su nombre pero tendría que hacer un for para buscar si alguno coincide... y sería más  complicado. Algo así Usuario[nombre][id] y que se cargue dinamicamente Usuario[$nombre][$id] y cuando consulte Usuario["Lucas"][ID] me diese tú id que en este caso no uso id pero es un decir.